# Sql transaction what can come after

Tags: mysql, sql, sqltransaction

Can you please tell me why c and d are the right answers here ?
Thank you

> Select the statements that can be used to complete the following SQL code block

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Enrollments WHERE Accepted = 1
UPDATE Enrollments SET Accepted = 1 WHERE CourseTitle = ’Data Base’
```

(a) END TRANSACTION
(b) END
**(c) COMMIT
(d) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION**

Comment: `END` does not tell the database what you want to do with the transaction: You can either **commit** the changes, which means that you want to keep them or discard them by **rolling** them **back**. Having defined `END` in the sense of one of the two former would you to require which semantics it now carries, while the other two are clear by themselves – and that's why it simply hasn't ever been defined alike in SQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because those are the SQL key words that can be used to end a transaction

COMMIT will submit your transaction and end it.

While ROLLBACK will, as its name suggests roll the database back to how it was before the transaction was started.